# How to store encrypted data in microsoft sql database and retrieve it and decrypt it

Tags: php, sql-server, encryption

**Am using the class below to encrypt and decrypt my data**

```
    <?php

class ConnectionInfo  
{
    public $mServerName;
    public $mConnectionInfo;
    public $conn;

    public function GetConnection()
    {
        # code...
        $this->mServerName =  "DESKTOP-ES2IEHB\SQLEXPRESS";
        $this->mConnectionInfo =  array("Database"=>"thefaithdb");
        $this->conn = sqlsrv_connect($this->mServerName,$this->mConnectionInfo);

        return $this->conn;
    }

    public function my_simple_crypt( $string, $action = 'e',$algo ) {
        // you may change these values to your own
        $secret_key = 'my_simple_secret_key';
        $secret_iv = 'my_simple_secret_iv';

        $output = false;
        $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
        $key = hash( $algo, $secret_key );
        $iv = substr( hash( $algo, $secret_iv ), 0, 16 );

        if( $action == 'e' ) {
            $output = base64_encode( openssl_encrypt( $string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv ) );
        }
        else if( $action == 'd' ){
            $output = openssl_decrypt( base64_decode( $string ), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv );
        }

        return $output;
    }

}


?>
```

When i use the class to decrypt data and encrypt without storing in a database, it works well when the string is of all length

```
 <?php
 require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/Secure.php');
$mainpass = "ALSONG DUSTAN PHILANDER";
//MD5 encryption

$options = [
    'cost' => 12,
];

$mSecure = new SecurityClass();


$encrypted = $mSecure->my_simple_crypt( $mainpass, 'e','sha512' );

$decrypted = $mSecure->my_simple_crypt($encrypted, 'd','sha512' );


echo "encrypted $encrypted<br/>";
echo "decrypted $decrypted<br/>";



?>
```

This is the output 
[It is in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP4c4.png)

Now when i store that mssql database with this code

```
    <?php
 require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/ConnectionInfo.php' );

 //Get up our connection
 $mConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo ();
 $mConnectionInfo->GetConnection();

 if ($mConnectionInfo->conn) {
     # code...
     echo "Connected<br/>";
 }


       $encrypted = $mConnectionInfo->my_simple_crypt('ALSONG DUSTAN PHILANDER'  , 'e','sha384' );
        $myparams['Item_Name'] = $encrypted;

        $encrypted2 = $mConnectionInfo->my_simple_crypt('56'  , 'e','sha384' );
        $myparams['Item_Age'] = $encrypted2;



        $parameters = array(array(&$myparams['Item_Name'],SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                            array(&$myparams['Item_Age'],SQLSRV_PARAM_IN));

        $sql = "EXEC spGetUser @Item_Name = ? , @Item_Age = ? ";

        $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($mConnectionInfo->conn,$sql,$parameters);

        $work = sqlsrv_execute($stmt);

        if ($work) {
            # code...
            echo "Successful $encrypted<br/>";
        }
        else {
            # code...
            echo "Connection Failed.<br/>";
            die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
        }
?>
```

Which is successfull, then when i want to retrieve it back from the database using a stored procedure

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetAge]
    @Item_Name nvarchar(max) 
AS
    SELECT Name AS IDName,Age FROM [User] WHERE Name = @Item_Name
RETURN 0
```

Then this is the php code to retrieve it

```
<?php
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/ConnectionInfo.php' );


        //Get up our connection
        $mConnectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo ();
        $mConnectionInfo->GetConnection();

        if ($mConnectionInfo->conn) {
            # code...
            echo "Connected<br/>";
        }

       $encrypted1 = $mConnectionInfo->my_simple_crypt('ALSONG DUSTAN PHILANDER'  , 'e','sha384' );
         $myparams2['Item_Name'] = $encrypted1;

         $params = array(array(&$myparams2['Item_Name'],SQLSRV_PARAM_IN));


         $sql2 = "EXEC spGetAge @Item_Name = ?";
         $stmt2 = sqlsrv_prepare($mConnectionInfo->conn,$sql2,$params);
         $work = sqlsrv_execute($stmt2);




        if(!$stmt2)
        {
            echo "Query failed <br/>";
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
        }
        else{
         $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt2,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

         $name = $row['IDName'];
         if ($name==null) {
             # code...
             echo "Empty";
         }

        $decrypted = $mConnectionInfo->my_simple_crypt($row['IDName'], 'd','sha384' );
         $decrypted2 = $mConnectionInfo->my_simple_crypt($row['Age'], 'd','sha384' );


            echo "The age is $decrypted2 of $decrypted <br/>";
            echo  $row['IDName'] ;
            echo "<br/> The name is  $encrypted1";


        }



?>
```

The output is 
[In the link below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36W4n.png)

This problem only comes when my input string for encryption is more than 14 characters long. How can i make it possible to also work after i have stored it in the database and then decrypt it and it works perfectly. Thanks for the help

Comment: Check the type, and length, of the database field you store the data in. Why are you using a stored procedure for this?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware , i used nvarchar(max). I think that can work. And am using stored procedure to reduce SQL injections

Comment: In what way can a stored procedure 'reduce' SQL injection? I'm not familiar with that. What I do know is that binding parameters will do the job.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware , there is a way you dont be using the quotattion marks in your php file with your SQL query which can easily be affected by the injection

Comment: Found the solution, had to change data type to varchar(max)

Answer (score 0):

I feel like encryption by php is the wrong way to go anyways..
If you're storing your data in a sql server than you have all the tools you need there.
Give [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/encryption-hierarchy) article a shot. 
Once you know how many layers of encryption you want to use, create a certificate and keys on your server. 
If you wanna get the information on the sql server - write a stored procedure that uses your components on the mssql server and if you want to get it displayed, have a stored procedure ready to decrypt them(which you should have anyways because the data is not gonna be readable if not decrypted on the mssql server).